# Некорректное отображение внутренней тени в Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Разрабатываю небольшой сайт, тестировал только в Chrome (полагал, что браузеры уже современные и рендерят всё одинаково хорошо).

Сейчас поставил Firefox и приуныл: появилась проблема с отображением `:hover {box-shadow: inset`.
Заключается она в том, что тень отображается или только с одной стороны, или, чаще всего, "квадратной" (будто это не тень, а полупрозрачный `border` внутри контейнера). При применении `transition: box-shadow` всё вообще мерцает и отображается очень странно.

И самое главное это то, что проблема появляется совершенно случайно, то есть может появиться сразу после загрузки страницы и пропасть после обновления, но снова появиться после переключения вкладки или сворачивания/разворачивания браузера. Иногда два наведения подряд дают разные результаты. `-moz-box-shadow` по каким-то причинам вообще не работает. Периодически баг проявляется и без `transition` или `:hover`. В Chrome всё идеально.

Пример кода, на котором можно уловить баг (но сложнее, чем на полном сайте, не знаю, почему):

```css
.accent1:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* DOESN'T WORK AT ALL */
}
.test {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgb(0, 150, 150);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: box-shadow .5s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="accent1 test">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Lorem</span>
      <span>ipsum</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: прежде всего, использовать `-moz-box-shadow` уже нет нужды, ибо, согласно [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow),браузеры поддерживают это свойство без вендорных префиксов. возможно, из-за этого у вас свойство дублируется и браузер не знат, как корректно обработать. по факту, у меня на Firefox 46.0.1 проблема не наблюдается. Возможно, вам стоит обновить браузер

Comment: @lexxl Нет, наличие вендорного префикса никак не влияет на проблему, Firefox вообще игнорирует его (префикс). Firefox установил два часа назад, версия 46.0.1, без плагинов и с дефолтными настройками.

Comment: вижу, что игнорирует. больше придраться не к чему было, вот и решил, чтоб стоит попробовать его удалить. и, кстати, оффтопик: есть мнение, что блочные элементы не следует вкладывать в строчные

Comment: @lexxl Знаю, что не следует, но в любом случае придётся извращаться: либо энкор тянуть на весь контейнер, либо на JS обработку вешать, либо вот так. Так хотя бы выглядит логично. Возможно, эта проблема лишь на рабочем компьютере, как-то связана с железом или системой. Но в любом случае Chrome работает нормально ведь.

Comment: @Urffly странно, но у меня что в лисе что в хроме, все одинаково. Ничего не прыгает